SendGrid API Callout From Flow Using Apex
I have queuable class which has a function to send out mails via sendgrid using REST API. I have created invocable apex action which is getting called from flow and is calling that queuable class using future method. But when i execute the flow for around 350 records it does sendout mails to only 7 records out of 350. So does anyone know why it is happening that or does anybody have any other approach of implementation so that all the 350 records can receive the mail.
public class SendSendGridEmailHelper {
   @future(callout=true)
   public static void enqueueSendGridEmail(String emailTemplateId, String subject, 
   String emailMessageId, String toAddress, String relatedObjectName, String relatedObjectId) {
    // Call the queueable class from the future method
    SendSendGridEmailQueueable queueableJob = new 
    SendSendGridEmailQueueable(emailTemplateId, subject, emailMessageId, toAddress, relatedObjectName, relatedObjectId);
    System.enqueueJob(queueableJob);
}}

 @InvocableMethod(label='Send Dynamic SendGrid Mail Action 2' callout=true)
public static void sendSendGridEmail(List<RequestParams> emailRequests) {
    System.debug('** emailRequests ** : ' + emailRequests);
    RequestParams request = emailRequests[0];
    SendSendGridEmailHelper.enqueueSendGridEmail(
        request.emailTemplateId,
        request.subject,
        request.emailMessageId,
        request.toAddress,
        request.relatedObjectName,
        request.relatedObjectId
    );
}

public class SendSendGridEmailQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

// Define member variables to hold inputs
private String emailTemplateId;
private String subject;
private String emailMessageId;
private String toAddress;
private String relatedObjectName;
private String relatedObjectId;


// Constructor to initialize member variables
public SendSendGridEmailQueueable(String emailTemplateId, String subject, String emailMessageId, String toAddress, String relatedObjectName, String relatedObjectId) {
    this.emailTemplateId = emailTemplateId;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.emailMessageId = emailMessageId;
    this.toAddress = toAddress;
    this.relatedObjectName = relatedObjectName;
    this.relatedObjectId = relatedObjectId;
    
}

// Implement the execute method required by Queueable interface

public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    // Call your method to send email
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        // Avoid making the actual callout during the test
        System.debug('Skipping the callout in test mode.');
        return;
    }
    System.debug('Queueable Apex Executed');
    SendSendGridMailAction.getDataAndSendSendGridEmail(emailTemplateId, subject, emailMessageId, toAddress, relatedObjectName, relatedObjectId);
    System.debug('Queueable Job ID: ' + context.getJobId());
   
}}


is the flow a screen flow or a record-triggered flow?  If the latter, you need to invoke the queueable for every element in emailRequests. This can be done with chained queueables; future is not required here

It's scheduled flow. I tried to implement with queuable apex but it is giving error of "Too many queuable jobs added to the queue 2". So i had to implement the future method for that.

One would invoke the queueable once passing all emailrequests; the queueable plucks element 0, does the callout, and then enqueues itself with the remainder of the emailRequests (i.e. elements 1...200); this avoid the "too many queueables"
